# How to add listagg to code provided in SQL

Tags: sql, listagg, aginity

I have been given work to do regarding trading, I want to find the buyer and seller of different assets, I have the data for who the buyer and the seller are for each trade but I've been told to use the LISTAGG function on the data sets which are BUYR or SELLR so it would be displayed as (buyer) - (seller) with the dash separating them

```
SELECT nvl(fi.id, fi.fininstrmgnlattrbts_id) AS isin, entity_nm, id.type, subtype, id.lei
FROM mbi_anon.vw_dz_red_mm_txn_tx tx
LEFT JOIN mbi_anon.tmp_ref_mm_lei_data lei
ON tx.exctgpty = lei.lei_cde
LEFT JOIN mbi_anon.vw_dz_red_mm_txn_fininstrm fi 
ON tx.splmtrydata_mdptransactionid = fi.splmtrydata_mdptransactionid
LEFT JOIN mbi_anon.vw_dz_red_mm_txn_identity id
ON tx.splmtrydata_mdptransactionid = id.splmtrydata_mdptransactionid
WHERE nvl(fi.id, fi.fininstrmgnlattrbts_id) IN ('SE0007126', 'SE0007525', 'SE0010296', 'SE0010296', 'CH0445689', 'SE0011414', 'SE0011414') 
LIMIT 1000;
```

What this code gives me is a table with 5 column; ISIN of a contract, the company, type which will state either 'BUYR' or 'SELLR', the account type so whether its the account owner or a decision maker and the LEI code

Comment: I added the relevant tag for the DBMS

Comment: Have you done any research ? For example this: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/sql-academy/latest/sql-academy.pdf